# How would I go about create this function

Tags: scheme, racket

How would I create an approximate cos function.

What I have so far.

```
 (define k 0) 
(define (approx-cos x n) 
  (cond
    [(> 0 n) 0]
    [else (*  (/ (expt -1 k) (factorial (* 2 k))) (expt x (* 2 k)))]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution requires *a lot* of work before it meets the expectations. For starters, your parameters are switched: the first one is the number you want to calculate and the second one is the number of iterations...

Which leads me to the *major* problem in your solution, you're not iterating at all! You're supposed to call `approx-cos` at some point, or some helper procedure to do the looping (as I did).

Last but not least, you're not correctly implementing the formula. Where's the `-1` part, for instance? Or where are you multiplying by `x^2k`? I'm afraid a complete rewrite is in order:

```
; main procedure
(define (approx-cos x n)
  ; call helper procedure
  (loop 0 0 x n))

; define a helper procedure
(define (loop acc k x n)
  ; loop with k from 0 to n, accumulating result
  (cond [(> k n) acc] ; return accumulator
        [else
         (loop (+ acc ; update accumulator
                  (* (/ (expt -1.0 k) ; implement the formula
                        (factorial (* 2.0 k)))
                     (expt x (* 2.0 k))))
               (add1 k) ; increment iteration variable
               x n)]))
```

This will pass all the check expects:

```
(approx-cos 0 0)
=> 1
(approx-cos (/ pi 2) 0)
=> 1
(approx-cos 0 10)
=> 1
(approx-cos pi 10)
=> -0.9999999999243502
(approx-cos (* 3 (/ pi 2)) 9)
=> -1.1432910825361444e-05
(approx-cos 10 100)
=> -0.8390715290756897
```

Some final thoughts: your implementation of `factorial` is very slow, if you plan to do a larger number of iterations, your `factorial` will freeze the execution at some point.

Comment: @loren an `if` is the same as a `cond`, but just for one condition. And the _named `let`_ that I'm using, it's the same as writing a helper procedure, which you need anyway. It should be pretty easy to rewrite my solution to a way you're more familiar with.

Comment: @loren Not quite. I rewrote it in a way more familiar to you.

Comment: Thank you oscar, one question for the helper function loop it says n is not defined, would i need to add another variable n in this function?

Comment: It's supposed to take the outer `n`, but it seems that the language you're using doesn't support it :( ok, it's updated now.